# Ctrl keys not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a big incognito here: After some time without use my laptop (kind a month), both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys stopped work in functions like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, etc.

Ok, this might be a broken connector or malfunction keyboard, but when I try my keyboard on a online tester both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys works! To be more strange, when I do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ click in a web browser link to open in a new tab, works fine. Also, when I have something in my clipboard and do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

The problem seems to be very specific.

P.S. I did [all this tests](https://ccm.net/forum/affich-28177-control-keys-not-working-on-laptop) and reinstalled my windows too.

Comment: Do you have a clipboard tool, or something like that running (Autohotkey?)? You could plug in an alternate keyboard by USB to show if OS is working. You could boot from a live Linux USB (like Kubuntu; use Rufus/Etcher to make one) to show if the keyboard works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>Insert</kbd> key. This is what worked for me.

Comment: [Why have you submitted an identical answer to multiple questions?](https://superuser.com/questions/1611011/both-ctrl-keys-are-not-working-on-my-laptop).  Questions that have the same solution should be flagged as duplicate instead of being answered.

Answer (score 2):

Copy & paste the following command into PowerShell to check for any keyboard remapping in the registry:

```
$KB = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout'
Get-Item $KB
```

Does it display a property named 'ScanCode Map'?

```
PS C:\> $KB = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout'                                
PS C:\> gi $kb                                                                                        

    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control


Name                           Property
----                           --------
Keyboard Layout                Export ScanCode Map : {0, 0, 0, 0...}
                               Demo ScanCode Map   : {0, 0, 0, 0...}
                               ScanCode Map        : {0, 0, 0, 0...}


PS C:\>
```

If that value exists, it is quite likely remapping your keys. It does not exist by default & can be deleted. Sign out & back in for deletion to take effect.

Comment: Hello Keith. I dont have any property returned as response. After that I restarted my computer and problem persists. Am I forgeting something?

Comment: Doesn't sound like it. The value doesn't exist by default. Have you tried Safe Mode?

Comment: Tried just now. Same problem. Works on virtual keyboard, but doens't work for Ctrl + C and Ctrl + A