# Both Ctrl keys are not working on my laptop

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop, hotkeys, ctrl

I have a Lenovo ideapad 700 and both of my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys are not working.
Up to this point, I have tried for possible solutions. It can not be that both of my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys are broken.

I have checked updating, uninstalling the keyboard drivers, checking going on safe mode and seeing if it works there, without any success. Checked the following link [HERE](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/both-ctrl-keys-not-working/3bd8609c-0a47-4f6d-93a6-f863d1936233#:%7E:text=Method%202%3A%20Run%20the%20Hardware%20and%20Devices%20Troubleshooter.&text=Press%20Windows%20key%20%2B%20X%2C%20select,top%20right%20to%20Large%20icons.&text=the%20left%20panel.-,Run%20the%20Hardware%20and%20devices%20troubleshooter.,if%20the%20issue%20is%20resolved.), or [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1531297/ctrl-keys-not-working-on-windows-10), [here](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/both-ctrl-keys-not-working.3570983/)

I have checked also similar questions here, without any success.

This fact that my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>V</kbd> are not working, it is making my workflow very difficult.

Comment: Tried booting from a linux live USB stick and checking there?  This will help you isolate if it is the OS or the HARDWARE.

Comment: "Every single possible solution" would have included testing an external keyboard &/or replacing the internal keyboard.. so I'd conclude not **everything** has yet been tried.

Comment: I have updated my question .

Comment: try opening the on screen keyboard and seeing if your keystrokes show up there. (assuming windows 10)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ctrl keys not working on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1531297/ctrl-keys-not-working-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Lenovo ideapad 700 15isk both  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys not working.
It is no BIOS or software problem, it's hardware.
I fixed mine by opening the lid, tacking off the battery, disconnecting the keyboard, and putting a piece of paper 1 mm tick on the keyboard cable to keep  pressure.
It worked, if it doesn't work try trimming half a mm 1/2 mm from the keyboard cable.
That works as well....

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Swap function enabled scenario:

> "1-Open system CONTROL PANEL.  If it does not appear as shown below,
> make sure VIEW BY is set to SMALL ICONS or LARGE ICONS.  You could
> also try searching for KEYBOARD in search box. Windows 10 Control
> Panel with Small Icons Displayed, Screen capture When your keyboard
> shortcut copy past undo redo keys do not work try to check this
> setting
>
> 2-Select your manufacturers keyboard manager.  Note this is a
> different place than just the KEYBOARD.  In my control panel, it says
> LENOVO – KEYBOARD MANAGER.
>
> 3-Select Fn key and Ctrl key swap tab.  Then verify Swap Function is
> turned OFF.  Mine was turned ON by default, which meant the keys were
> reversed on my keyboard and I didn’t even know it!"
> [From here](https://www.virtuallabrats.com/blog/1-easy-setting-how-to-fix-system-keyboard-shortcuts-not-working-ctrl-c-ctrl-v-etc-windows-10/)

- 

Same idea as "Señor CMasMas". I'd recommend using puppy linux as a live test distro. It has a lot of drivers and tools already available.

Then, have you tried to uninstall the keyboard driver? if not >>  [try this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-v-not-working/aa6719c6-9787-4e99-9c57-7ea89c5dbaeb)

(If Win OS)

1. Click Start
2. Control Panel
3. Printers and Other Hardware
4. Keyboard
5. In the Keyboard Properties window, click Hardware
6. Click Properties
7. Click Driver
8. Click Uninstall, click OK
9. Restart your Computer

Comment: I  have tried both of these alternative solutions and neither worked

Comment: External keyboard does the same?